# lua program shows current time

Tags: date, lua, timestamp

This is a piece of lua script that displays the time. I cannot separate the numbers ie: `time.hour, ":"`,
to basically show *hh:mm:ss*

```
time = os.date("*t")
print(time.hour .. time.min .. time.sec)
```

Comment: I've not used Lua much, but wouldn't a basic `print(time.hour .. ":" .. time.min .. ":" .. time.sec)` do it?

Comment: works just fine, I was having an error somewhere else in my script

Comment: Otherwise, `print(os.date("%H:%M:%S"))` would seem to do it also. http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use string concatenation: `print(time.hour .. ":" .. time.min .. ":" .. time.sec)`
2. Use formatting: `print(("%02d:%02d:%02d"):format(time.hour, time.min, time.sec))`
3. Use table concatenation: `print(table.concat({time.hour, time.min, time.sec}, ":"))`

When you really need to format your string, my preference would be for #2. For `time = {hour = 1, min = 20, sec = 5}` this prints:

```
1:20:5
01:20:05
1:20:5
```

Answer (score 2):

For simply printing the time - extract what you want (the time) from the full date stamp string:

```
  > os.date():sub(9)
    12:30:39
```

This works on my PC ;). There may be a [different date stamp string](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.date) in your OS.

G

Answer (score 2):

```
local date = os.date('*t')
local time = os.date("*t")
print(os.date("%A, %m %B %Y | "), ("%02d:%02d:%02d"):format(time.hour, time.min, time.sec))`
```

[image]